# Flash camera widget resets on .append() to a div

Tags: jquery, html, flash

I have a flash code to display webcam feed to the user. where user can choose from a list of camera's and microphone's. once shown to user, user selects his desired webcam and microphone. but after I append the widget to another div the user chosen webcam and microphone are reset and user has to again select them.

I have to show the flash widget in different html divs at different times, but it should not always be visible.

**Like:**

`1. Initially it is on the page body with css(display:none);`

`2. I move it to a pop-up div using .append(), and change css(display:block), the camera initialises, and user chooses his desired webcam and microphone;`

`3. Again I  append it to body from pop-up div, but this time it again reinitialises itself, and user has to again choose the webcam and microphone as his selected one's get reset in the list.`

while I don't want it to reinitialise but just to continue ahead with the settings

as it was already initialised when display was turned to block in
    the pop-up.

This happens with Chrome and Opera mainly. Things work fine in Firefox.

Any way to keep flash initialised after appending it to other div.?